# d3.geoPath(projection) not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geo

I'm working on Mike Bostock's code (d3 v4): https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4136647. Also, in jsfiddle if you want to run it: https://jsfiddle.net/r3bxmhLe/

In this code, he doesn't use any explicit projection.

```
var path = d3.geoPath();
```

But I need to use an explicit projection as I'll have to convert some long, lat to x, y. And I want to use the same projection for drawing the map. So I wanted to change the above line to:

```
var proj = d3.AlbersUsa();
var path = d3.geoPath(proj);
```

I also tried

```
var proj = d3.AlbersUsa();
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(proj);
```

This produces lots of random lines instead of the map. So, the projection is not working. What am I missing?

Note that the above projection works fine when I do `proj([long, lat])`

Comment: The docs(https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#path_projection) say:  If projection is not specified, returns ... null. The null projection represents the identity transformation: the input geometry is not projected and is instead rendered directly in raw coordinates. This can be useful for fast rendering of `pre-projected geometry`...

Comment: So when your source file already has pre-projected geometry, it makes sense that applying projection again does not produce the right results. Either use another map source file or apply a transform to convert to the new coordinates.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I'll probably search for a different topojson file then. Still, could you please elaborate on the transform idea? Are you suggesting I write a transformation function myself or is there an easy way to do it? I'm sort of new to mapping (d3 or otherwise).

Comment: I think that depends on what you want to achieve. You can apply all kinds of geometric transformations to your map and see if you like the results.https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#transforms

Comment: Also, if you have another set of coordinates that you want to place on this map, then you can consider applying the projection function directly to those points instead of the base map.

Comment: I'm applying the projection function directly to my long, lat coordinates. But the result doesn't line up with the pre-built topojson data: http://i.imgur.com/A7EiKcs.png
I can try and adjust the points locations applying scale and translate on projection, but that seems a crude of dealing with this.

Comment: Well, you can always create your own map (https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c)

Comment: Besides, if you look at the source json file, there is some scale and transform data there which might help you pinpoint the correct values

Comment: Yes, I ended up making my own map. Thanks for all the helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using topJSON which is specifically works with geoPath Method if you pass anything else into it you double project that getting the mess.

I ran into this

it seems the default projection is 
const projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa().scale(1280).translate([480, 300]);

with d3 default topoJSON.